# What is bottom bar on navigationcontroller based view?

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, xcode6, xcode-storyboard

I started with a singleview app.  I then embedded a navigationcontroller.  At the bottom of the scene1, there is a bar.  It isn't anything I put there.  It doesn't show in the document outline but does obscure UI elements that I drag to the bottom of the view.

However, once I run the app, the bar is not visible.  Anyone know what this bar is?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thats called bottom bar of navigation controller,

```
navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES;
```

or with animation

```
[navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

Comment: What are you hiding?  Nothing displays at runtime.

Comment: In some of my navigationcontroller based views, I don't see this bar in IB.  Do you know what the difference is?

Answer (score 0):

In order to hide the bottom bar in the storyboard you have to select the view controller that contains that bar, go to "Attributes Inspector" > "Simulated metrics" and select "None" for the bottom bar.